# Export blade using laravel-dompdf version 2.0

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, barryvdh

i try to export a blade view using the package barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
but i get an error

> Undefined array key "" in
> /var/www/html/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php line 4752
> /var/www/html/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Adapter/CPDF.php", line: 806, function: "getFontHeight",
> .....
> etc.....
> /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/PdfController.php",
> line: 193

Here is my PdfController line 193

```
192: $pdf = Pdf::loadView("template.pdf"); 
193: Storage::disk('local')->put('public/pdf/test.pdf',$pdf->output());
```

here is my template/pdf.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PDF </title>
</head>

<body>TEST</body>
</html>
```

but when I try with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf version 1.0, iIt outputs correctly.What's the problem?

Comment: Could you post the php version, laravel version

Comment: @DeepeshThapa I use PHP version 8 and laravel version 9

Comment: did you figure it out? I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Pdf::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
$pdf = Pdf::loadView("template.pdf");
Storage::disk('local')->put('public/pdf/test.pdf',$pdf->output());
```

Comment: I tried. but it doesn't work. $pdf->output, $pdf->download() and $pdf->stream() shows the same error

Comment: Can you delete `dompdf_font_family_cache.php` file from `storage/fonts`. And check again?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).